# How do I convert between 2D paper space coordinates world 3D coordinates for AEC models in a forge viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, viewer, aec

I'm following a blog [post](https://forge.autodesk.com/ja/node/1765) by Petr Broz with my published views from a Revit project in BIM 360, but I was wondering how I would convert between 2D coordinates and 3D world coordinates if my published 2D view is actually just a stand-alone floor plan view without being placed on any sheet.

I was trying to get the viewport but I realized the published view doesn't have any viewport in the model. So I cannot actually use those functions in the extension for viewports. Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My mistake was manually trying to convert x,y,z coordinates by dividing them with the viewport scale, thus they couldn't align with 3D world coordinates.

By providing the correct model unitscale, I could get the transform with get3DTo2DMatrix().

```
    viewport = viewportExt.getViewports(viewer.model)[0];
    viewportXform viewport.get3DTo2DMatrix(viewer.model.getUnitScale());
    
    // From foot to millimeters
    x = x* 0.00328084;
    y = y* 0.00328084;
    z = z* 0.00328084;
    var worldPt = new THREE.Vector3(x,y,z);
    worldPt.applyMatrix4(viewportXform);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it doesn't support floor plan view without placing the sheet, since there is some required information missing at this moment. We are still discussing this with our engineering team.

The current working path is creating a Revit Sheet view and placing the floor plan inside, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smMap86YZUY

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I decided to just place the views in sheets. now I can get the viewports to work with. But I'm still unsure how to translate the world coordinates to sheet space coordinate. In Petr's post, he is translating Canvas coordinates to 3D coordinates but I am trying to translate the other direction. I have set of world coordinates of elements that I can display on 3D view with globalOffset already. but I cant find globalOffset for 2D space.  how should I align the offset of world coordinates to a viewport ?

Comment: To map 3D coordinates to 2D, you will need to get the transform from `Autodesk.AEC.AecModelData.get3DTo2DMatrix`. https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/mapping-between-sheets-and-3d-views-aec-models